# Java Swing: Reusing a parent JPanel graphics2D reference in child JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

I am relatively new to Java *Swing* and I have a use case where I have a single `JPanel` that needs to be divided into 2 equal sections horizontally.
Each section needs to display a graph with added features.
The first section would be a simple line graph.
The second would be a line graph plus bar chart rendered in one single graph.

The application is supposed to be using a decorator pattern approach, where the simple line graph would be the base that needs to be rendered first and then using the same base the extra feature (decorator) of bar graph needs to be added on it. In order to achieve this, how can I pass a single graphics object to my decorator pattern classes?

I am expecting something like this.
[image: Reference Image]

Comment: *"how can I pass a single graphics object to my decorator pattern classes?"* you don't.  Each panel will have it's own `Graphics` context, which you can get access to via one of the paint methods.  This would then be passed to the "renderer/delegate" (or decorator in your case)

Comment: You should have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have the decorator generate an `Image` which could then either be added to the panel via a `JLabel` or painted based on your needs

Comment: Do you have any questions about my answer?

Answer (score 2):

> The application is supposed to be using a decorator pattern approach, where the simple line graph would be the base that needs to be rendered first and then using the same base the extra feature (decorator) of bar graph needs to be added on it. In order to achieve this, how can I pass a single graphics object to my decorator pattern classes?

Your question is in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I do such-and-such" when the best solution is to use a completely different approach entirely.

For one, you do ***not*** want to pass a single Graphics object around but rather each JPanel would use its own Graphics object that gets passed to it by the JVM via its `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` Graphics parameter. Instead, you would share the same data, and could draw the parent's graphics by calling a painting method of the panel to be decorated within the current JPanel's `paintComponent` method. This should draw the line graph. You could then use the shared data to draw the additional things after that line of code.

Note also that usually the decorator pattern would be used for your GUI application's *model*, the non-GUI brains that holds the program's state (its data) and behaviors (its logical methods), and not its *view*, the GUI portion of the program. The view is mainly responsible for displaying visually the model's state, as well as possibly allowing for user input. Otherwise I would find it most unusual to pass a parent JPanel into a child's constructor and decorate on top of that, .... but that is not impossible to do, just unusual, and prone to errors.

---

I suppose that you could use actual JPanels in a decorator fashion, having them all extend from a decorator interface, such as,...

```
public interface DecoratorPanel {
    int[] getData();

    int convertDatumToY(int i);

    int convertItoX(int i);

    void drawGraph(Graphics g);
    
    public int getGap();
}
```

and then have the parent panel draw the line, perhaps something like:

```
public class ParentPanel extends JPanel implements DecoratorPanel {
    // ...
    private int[] data;
    // ...

    // ...
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // this should not be called by children
        drawGraph(g);
    }

    // this allows children to call graphics code without calling 
    // super.paintComponent
    public void drawGraph(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            int x1 = convertItoX(i - 1);
            int y1 = convertDatumToY(data[i - 1]);
            int x2 = convertItoX(i);
            int y2 = convertDatumToY(data[i]);
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

And then a decorator JPanel could perhaps use the paintComponent output from this parent:

```
public class ChildBoxPanel extends JPanel implements DecoratorPanel {
    private static final int BC = 245;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(BC, BC, BC);
    private DecoratorPanel panelToBeDecorated;

    public ChildBoxPanel(DecoratorPanel panelToBeDecorated) {
        if (panelToBeDecorated == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("panelToBeDecorated is null");
        }
        this.panelToBeDecorated = panelToBeDecorated;
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getData() {
        // delegate many things to the "seed" JPanel
        return panelToBeDecorated.getData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawGraph(g);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void drawGraph(Graphics g) {
        panelToBeDecorated.drawGraph(g);
        
        // here would go the new drawing specific for this JPanel
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for (int i = 0; i < getData().length; i++) {
            int x = convertItoX(i);
            int y = convertDatumToY(getData()[i]);
            g2.fillRect(x - getGap(), y - getGap(), 2 * getGap(), 2 * getGap());
        }
    }   
    
   // ...
    
}
```

I have tested this code and it *works*, as shown below:

[image]

Another possible solution would be to decorate BufferedImages -- something for my next project!